# Total time elapsed between the first fund addition and fund withdrawal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:a positive value of LIQUIDITY_adj means fund addition and negative implies withdrawal. I want to compute time elapsed between the first liquidity addition until the whole funds are withdrawn.

```
    BLOCK_TIMESTAMP NF_TOKEN_ID LIQUIDITY_adj   LIQUIDITY_cumsum
0   2021-05-04 22:11:00+00:00   33.0    3.470648e+17    3.470648e+17
1   2021-05-04 22:42:08+00:00   33.0    -3.470648e+17   0.000000e+00
2   2021-05-05 02:10:21+00:00   41.0    2.299857e+14    2.299857e+14
3   2021-05-05 02:21:03+00:00   41.0    1.373000e+10    2.299995e+14
4   2021-05-05 02:30:25+00:00   41.0    -2.299995e+14   0.000000e+00
5   2021-05-05 17:57:32+00:00   141.0   1.163028e+23    1.163028e+23
6   2021-05-05 20:24:07+00:00   141.0   -1.163028e+23   0.000000e+00
7   2021-05-05 18:05:11+00:00   151.0   4.127229e+16    4.127229e+16
8   2021-05-05 18:10:41+00:00   151.0   -4.127229e+16   0.000000e+00
9   2021-05-05 18:06:06+00:00   152.0   9.695097e+20    9.695097e+20
10  2021-05-05 18:08:55+00:00   152.0   -9.695097e+20   0.000000e+00
11  2021-05-05 18:08:16+00:00   157.0   1.377613e+20    1.377613e+20
12  2021-05-05 18:09:23+00:00   157.0   -1.377613e+20   0.000000e+00
13  2021-05-05 18:18:36+00:00   157.0   1.199888e+19    1.199888e+19
14  2021-05-05 23:31:48+00:00   157.0   -1.199888e+19   0.000000e+00
```

I tried

```
lp_shortterm['DURATION_HR'] = lp_shortterm.groupby('NF_TOKEN_ID')['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

and got this

```
BLOCK_TIMESTAMP NF_TOKEN_ID LIQUIDITY_adj   LIQUIDITY_cumsum    DURATION_HR
0   2021-05-04 22:11:00+00:00   33.0    3.470648e+17    3.470648e+17    NaN
1   2021-05-04 22:42:08+00:00   33.0    -3.470648e+17   0.000000e+00    0.518889
2   2021-05-05 02:10:21+00:00   41.0    2.299857e+14    2.299857e+14    NaN
3   2021-05-05 02:21:03+00:00   41.0    1.373000e+10    2.299995e+14    0.178333
4   2021-05-05 02:30:25+00:00   41.0    -2.299995e+14   0.000000e+00    0.156111
5   2021-05-05 17:57:32+00:00   141.0   1.163028e+23    1.163028e+23    NaN
6   2021-05-05 20:24:07+00:00   141.0   -1.163028e+23   0.000000e+00    2.443056
7   2021-05-05 18:05:11+00:00   151.0   4.127229e+16    4.127229e+16    NaN
8   2021-05-05 18:10:41+00:00   151.0   -4.127229e+16   0.000000e+00    0.091667
9   2021-05-05 18:06:06+00:00   152.0   9.695097e+20    9.695097e+20    NaN
10  2021-05-05 18:08:55+00:00   152.0   -9.695097e+20   0.000000e+00    0.046944
11  2021-05-05 18:08:16+00:00   157.0   1.377613e+20    1.377613e+20    NaN
12  2021-05-05 18:09:23+00:00   157.0   -1.377613e+20   0.000000e+00    0.018611
13  2021-05-05 18:18:36+00:00   157.0   1.199888e+19    1.199888e+19    0.153611
14  2021-05-05 23:31:48+00:00   157.0   -1.199888e+19   0.000000e+00    5.220000
```

but the issue with this is, for instance, `NF_TOKEN_ID = 41`, there are two values for `DURATION_HR` but i just want one value which should be the difference between `2021-05-05 02:10:21+00:00` and `2021-05-05 02:30:25+00:00` . For `NF_TOKEN_ID = 157` there should be two values since funds are added/withdrawn twice. Basically, values `DURATION_HR` should  only exists where the value of `LIQUIDITY_cumsum` is 0.

Comment: It's probably simpler to remove the values after the groupby. `df.loc[ df['LIQUIDITY_cumsum'] != 0, 'DURATION_HR' ] = NaN`?

Comment: then i can't compute the position duration...

Comment: I mean after the whole groupby/.diff() computation. From the result you've shown - you just want to `NaN` the `0` cumsum values, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this can be divided into groups. Here in `'ind'` took indexes where: `'LIQUIDITY_cumsum' == 0.0`. Through `df.loc[ind, 'cs']` the numbers ind.  Empty values are `filled` with the first non-np.nan value that comes first. The result is a 'cs' column, which is marked up into groups.

Grouping by two columns: `'NF_TOKEN_ID', 'cs'` and through the `fff` function the necessary values are set for: 'DURATION_HR'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'])

ind = df[df['LIQUIDITY_cumsum'] == 0.0].index
df.loc[ind, 'cs'] = list(ind)
df['cs'] = df['cs'].fillna(method='bfill')
df['DURATION_HR'] = np.nan


def fff(x):
    df.loc[x.index[-1], 'DURATION_HR'] = \
        (df.loc[x.index[-1], 'BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] -
         df.loc[x.index[0], 'BLOCK_TIMESTAMP']).total_seconds()/3600

df.groupby(['NF_TOKEN_ID', 'cs'])['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'].apply(fff)

print(df[['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP', 'NF_TOKEN_ID', 'LIQUIDITY_cumsum', 'cs', 'DURATION_HR']])
```

Output

```
             BLOCK_TIMESTAMP  NF_TOKEN_ID  LIQUIDITY_cumsum   cs  DURATION_HR
0  2021-05-04 22:11:00+00:00         33.0      3.470648e+17  0.0          NaN
1  2021-05-04 22:42:08+00:00         33.0      0.000000e+00  0.0     0.518889
2  2021-05-05 02:10:21+00:00         41.0      2.299857e+14  1.0          NaN
3  2021-05-05 02:21:03+00:00         41.0      2.299995e+14  1.0          NaN
4  2021-05-05 02:30:25+00:00         41.0      0.000000e+00  1.0     0.334444
5  2021-05-05 17:57:32+00:00        141.0      1.163028e+23  2.0          NaN
6  2021-05-05 20:24:07+00:00        141.0      0.000000e+00  2.0     2.443056
7  2021-05-05 18:05:11+00:00        151.0      4.127229e+16  3.0          NaN
8  2021-05-05 18:10:41+00:00        151.0      0.000000e+00  3.0     0.091667
9  2021-05-05 18:06:06+00:00        152.0      9.695097e+20  4.0          NaN
10 2021-05-05 18:08:55+00:00        152.0      0.000000e+00  4.0     0.046944
11 2021-05-05 18:08:16+00:00        157.0      1.377613e+20  5.0          NaN
12 2021-05-05 18:09:23+00:00        157.0      0.000000e+00  5.0     0.018611
13 2021-05-05 18:18:36+00:00        157.0      1.199888e+19  6.0          NaN
14 2021-05-05 23:31:48+00:00        157.0      0.000000e+00  6.0     5.220000
```